# How to enable SSH on BusyBox without recompiling BusyBox?

Tags: linux, ssh, busybox, dropbear

I want to enable SSH service on BusyBox server (currently I can connect only via Telnet), so I think , that I need to compile SSH server , and send it to BusyBox router. So my question is - how to create SSH server binary to send it to BusyBox via FTP?

Comment: Just compile a SSH daemon for MIPS or whatever your router arch is and you won't have to recompile all of busybox.

Comment: @MeetTitan how to get known what is my router's arch? What command I should enter to get it?

Comment: That would be hard to pinpoint without some environment specific information, such as which model of router you're using and which firmware it is running.

Comment: You'll probably want to start by mounting the root partition as read/write because most routers are configured to mount / as read only. So, figure out your router arch, compile a compatible binary (Perhaps with static linked libs), upload to a temp folder, give the binary executable permissions, remount / as RW if needed, and move your binary to a folder within your $PATH variable. Then you'll want to check if `/etc/rc.local` exists and throw any commands you'd like run on boot in there. **WARNING, YOU MAY BRICK YOUR ROUTER IF YOU EITHER ENTER A COMMAND THAT DOES NOT RETURN, OR ERRORS OUT!!!**

Comment: openwrt is available for many routers and has dropbear support...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're taking a wrong direction.

> 1/ "How to enable SSH on BusyBox."

You can't.

> 2/ And "without recompiling BusyBox?"

You won't, because #1.

Because `busybox` in itself does not provide an SSH server nor client.

Now that your question is answered:

The usual way to add an SSH server to a `busybox` based system is to add `dropbear`, first on the list of "tiny utilities whose functionality is not provided by `busybox`":

https://busybox.net/tinyutils.html

https://matt.ucc.asn.au/dropbear/dropbear.html

How to compile `dropbear` (because *you will have to*), then install and run on your system is now another topic, on which no one can help you without further details on your target system or your cross toolchain.

Comment: Because you will have to ->> https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=767433. Already compiled dropbear.